# Is there a parameter to set up the number of digits in the watchlist of TradingView

Tags: tradingview-api

On the watchlist of my TradingView account there are quotations with several digits after the decimal point and others just 1 digit.

I would like to know if there is a way to set up on my watchlist the number of digits after the decimal point (for example XBTUSD at 54703.4 would be at 54703.42).

Thank you for your help.

Best

[image: Screenshot of Watchlist in TradingView]

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. Precision is determined by the symbol's tick size.